# How can sudo be hidden in a command?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, sudo

On Linux Mint 20+, I don't have to type `sudo apt upgrade`. I only type `apt upgrade`, the prompt asks for sudo password and the command is executed with elevated privileges.

How is that achieved?

Comment: Does `type apt` return anything enlightening?

Comment: it returns `/usr/local/bin/apt`. If this file there is a line `command = ["sudo"] + command` and then something like `subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, so to my understanding, apt will launch another program that will be `sudo apt-get` ? Why isn't this the same on all distros?

Comment: Rather than "something like", please add your discovery to your question

Comment: It this a pure install, or are there site specific changes?  `/usr/local/…`  and `/opt/…` are for site specific changes, not for use by the OS supplier.

Comment: it's a pure install of linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon, I never touch anything in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said there's something like this in `/usr/local/bin/apt`:

```
command = ["sudo"] + command
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which looks like [a Python script](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintsystem/blob/8ae91d3bc38abc0674bf2397cfbc31401e8c616c/usr/local/bin/apt) that builds a command line and stacks `sudo` at the start, to save you the trouble.

It looks like the same script serves some other commands too, there's something about e.g. [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1470813#p1470813).

Now, if you like, you could check what `ls -ld /usr/local/bin/apt` says, to see if it's a symlink to the actual script or such. The code above and in the linked article looks like it uses the name the script is called under to find which program to actually run.

> Why isn't this the same on all distros?

Because the others haven't bothered to provide such a wrapper, possibly because they don't think it's worth it. While it's true that installing packages with `apt` is somewhat difficult without privileges, it does have other functions too, like `apt search`, which don't need privileges. In general, it's impossible to list all the programs that would need them. Something like `rm` might or might not need them depending on the situation.

And then you get the situation where you need to use `sudo` for some commands, but not for others, and that's confusing. (Probably some might also argue that users should be forced to type `sudo` every time, so that they stay aware of when they're using raised privileges.)

Comment: `apt` is not difficult to use without privileges! I often run `apt search` and `apt show` as my ordinary user (I think that requires my user to be a memer of some group, but I don't remember which), before proceeding to install a package (with privileges).

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, yep, point, I tend to only use `apt-cache search`. I guess `apt search` is similar but different.